# CMake Error: target name "test" is reserved or not valid

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

Environments:

MAC os: 10.12.6

CMake version: 3.8

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (add_executable):
  The target name "test" is reserved or not valid for certain CMake features, such as generator expressions, and may result in undefined behavior.
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(test)

# set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(test ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CMake includes some functionality for automated testing. I.e. there is an [`add_test`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_test.html) command and related stuff, so the name `test` is reserved. Just rename `test` into something else.

Comment: I don't think that is it. I put a completely arbitrary name and it fails

Answer (score 3):

It might be simple as a typo.
I got this because I put commas between arguments when adding a library.

```
add_library(Library, library.cpp, dialogs.cpp)
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be an issue related to syntax in CMakeLists.txt.
I was getting a similar error when I was experimenting with Android NDK.

In my case, I made mistake while declaring C++ files in CMakeLists.txt. The correct way to declare C++ files are below :

```
add_library( 
           Your-library-name 

           # Sets the library as a shared library.
           SHARED

           # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
           your-cpp-file1.cpp
           your-cpp-file2.cpp
           your-cpp-file3.cpp 
       )
```