# CMake & CTest: How do I modify 'make' to only build and 'make test' to build and run tests?

Tags: cmake, ctest

How can I build AND run my tests with `make test`?

Currently, `make` builds all of my tests, and `make test` runs them. I'd like for `make` to only build the project without the tests, and `make test` to build and run the tests.

Top level CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Build tests
    mark_as_advanced( BUILD_TESTS )
    set( BUILD_TESTS true CACHE BOOL "Tests build target available if true" )
    if( BUILD_TESTS )
        enable_testing()
        add_subdirectory( tests )
    endif()
```

tests/CMakeLists.txt

```
foreach( APP ${TESTAPPS} )
 add_executable( "${APP}" "${APP}.c" ${src_files})
 add_test( NAME "${APP}_test" COMMAND "${APP}" )
endforeach( APP ${TESTAPPS} )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_executable(... EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
```

to exclude building from 'all'. `make` runs `make all`.

Then follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/15060921/9072753 :

```
add_custom_target(build_and_test ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} -V)
add_dependencies(build_and_test "${APP}")
add_test(....)
```

Comment: So with this solution I would actually build and run my tests with `make build_and_test` or whatever I choose the target name to be. It cannot be just `make test`?

Comment: `It cannot be just make test?` Yes. But I do not remember what happens when you do `add_custom_target(test`. Overall, you should be using `cmake --build` and `ctest` commands, not `make`.

Comment: This may happen: [CMake error target "test" is reserved or not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638704/cmake-error-target-name-test-is-reserved-or-not-valid). You can use "tests" though :)

Comment: I ended up following https://stackoverflow.com/a/56448477/14837560. Thank you this worked great!