# Error when Including Header File Utils.h : Undefined Reference `Utils::createShaderProgram`

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, glew

I want to show a green cube, in a directory there are `.cpp`, `.h`, and `.glsl` files:

1. main.cpp
2. Utils.h
3. vertShader.glsl
4. fragShader.glsl

I want to compile it using CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(test LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test GLEW GL glfw )
target_include_directories(test PUBLIC /root/SourceCodes/CPP/include/)
```

(I put the Utils.h in the /root/SourceCodes/CPP/include/ as well)

But, the problem is I get error:
**Undefined Reference `Utils::createShaderProgram`**

the codes / MWE for the files above:

main.cpp

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include "Utils.h"

using namespace std;

#define numVAOs 1
#define numVBOs 2

float cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ;
float cubeLocX, cubeLocY, cubeLocZ;
GLuint renderingProgram;
GLuint vao[numVAOs];
GLuint vbo[numVBOs];

GLuint mvLoc, projLoc;
int width, height;
float aspect;
glm::mat4 pMat, vMat, mMat, mvMat;

void setupVertices(void) { // 36 vertices, 12 triangles, makes 2x2x2 cube placed at origin
    float vertexPositions[108] = {
    -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
    };
    glGenVertexArrays(1,vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
    glGenBuffers(numVBOs, vbo);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions), vertexPositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void init(GLFWwindow* window){
    
    // Utils
    renderingProgram = Utils::createShaderProgram(
        "vertShader.glsl",
        "fragShader.glsl");
    cubeLocX = 0.0f; cubeLocY = -2.0f; cubeLocZ = 0.0f;
    setupVertices();
}

void display(GLFWwindow* window, double currentTime) {
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(renderingProgram);
    
    // get the uniform variables for the MV and projection matrices
    mvLoc = glGetUniformLocation(renderingProgram, "mv_matrix");
    projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(renderingProgram, "proj_matrix");

    // build perspective matrix
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    aspect = (float)width / (float)height;
    pMat = glm::perspective(1.0472f, aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f); // 1.0472 radians = 60 degrees

    // build view matrix, model matrix, and model-view matrix
    vMat = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(-cameraX, -cameraY, -cameraZ));
    mMat = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(cubeLocX, cubeLocY, -cubeLocZ));
    mvMat = vMat * mMat;

    // copy perspective and MV matrices to corresponding uniform variables
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mvMat));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(pMat));

    // associate VBO with the corresponding vertex attribute in the vertex shader
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    
    // adjust OpenGL settings and draw model
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,36);
}

int main(void)
{
    glfwInit(); //initialize GLFW and GLEW libraries
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(600, 600, " Learn Open GL with GLFW: Green Cube", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    
    init(window);
    
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        display(window, glfwGetTime());
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); 
    //return 0;
}
```

Utils.h

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
//#include <SOIL2/SOIL2.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

class Utils
{
private:
    static std::string readShaderFile(const char *filePath);
    static void printShaderLog(GLuint shader);
    static void printProgramLog(int prog);
    static GLuint prepareShader(int shaderTYPE, const char *shaderPath);
    static int finalizeShaderProgram(GLuint sprogram);

public:
    Utils();
    static bool checkOpenGLError();
    static GLuint createShaderProgram(const char *vp, const char *fp);
    static GLuint createShaderProgram(const char *vp, const char *gp, const char *fp);
    static GLuint createShaderProgram(const char *vp, const char *tCS, const char* tES, const char *fp);
    static GLuint createShaderProgram(const char *vp, const char *tCS, const char* tES, char *gp, const char *fp);
    static GLuint loadTexture(const char *texImagePath);
    static GLuint loadCubeMap(const char *mapDir);

    static float* goldAmbient();
    static float* goldDiffuse();
    static float* goldSpecular();
    static float goldShininess();

    static float* silverAmbient();
    static float* silverDiffuse();
    static float* silverSpecular();
    static float silverShininess();

    static float* bronzeAmbient();
    static float* bronzeDiffuse();
    static float* bronzeSpecular();
    static float bronzeShininess();
};
```

fragShader.glsl

```
#version 330

out vec4 color;

uniform mat4 mv_matrix;
uniform mat4 proj_matrix;

void main(void) {
    color = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

vertShader.glsl

```
#version 330

layout (location=0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 mv_matrix;
uniform mat4 proj_matrix;

void main(void) {
    gl_position = proj_matrix * mv_matrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: `Utils.h` declares a couple of member functions that are not defined. Do you perhaps a `Utils.cpp` somewhere? DId you compile and link it?

Comment: And for the record, an undefined reference is a *link* - time error; not compile time.

Comment: You asked the same question before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77306389/create-cmakefiles-to-compile-multiple-c-files-and-several-include-files which was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I have `Utils.cpp`, So I need to compile `Utils.cpp` with `Utils.h` then? compile `main.cpp` afterwards?

Comment: No it does not, this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fixit add more confusion. @463035818_is_not_an_ai might be of help for me.

Comment: Quite same question, someone told me to put the codes, so I put the codes, the difference is the code I put on this question is using OpenGL 3.3. Sorry not everyone already have high level advanced C++ knowledge. Some just try to follow a book, and the book has no clear explanation that's why I come to this forum.

Comment: Generally speaking, [edit] your post to include whatever additional information is needed. In this specific case, someone decided you're facing a special case of an unresolved symbol, which is 1) a common error and 2) every programmer should know how to fix it. No crime in not being a C++ expert (most people aren't). Because the community cannot walk everyone through fixing common errors, questions are closed as duplicates. If you're serious about C++, better learn to fix it now than later.

Comment: Thanks for that. I believe I was not born to be C++ expert. Just try to spend time to learn something useful, than playing around.

Comment: You have some hints to go on. You need to *define* your `Utils` class (look it up in your C++ book if you don't know what that means). Also go with wohlstad's comment in your closed question and do `add_executable(myexe <all your source files>)`. BTW, [don't name your target "test"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638704/cmake-error-target-name-test-is-reserved-or-not-valid).

Comment: Try `add_executable(test main.cpp Utils.cpp)`, or the full path to the cpp.

Comment: Alright thanks I will try it.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix does have the answer. To understand, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work/6264256#6264256.

Comment: I am able to get the wanted result. Yes we need `Utils.cpp`, I am able to do the compiling with `g++ *.cpp -o result -lGLEW -lglfw -lGL`, the CMake then can be modified from that, pardon me for the question above, but different people can't comprehend C++ books as fast as others who are talented. The book I read is not clear enough, it is just different way of learning and time to comprehend for different people.